# How to insert Hindi language in Mysql

Tags: mysql, hindi

I changed the charset as described [here](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/web-development/threads/361061/hindi-data-in-sql#post1542310) but does not work:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_hindi` (
  `data` varchar(1000) character set utf8 collate utf8_bin default NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
INSERT INTO `tbl_hindi` VALUES ('कंप्यूटर');
```

Answer (score 28):

The charset of the database needs to be `utf8_unicode_ci`.

Try creating a new database, as well as a new table.

```
CREATE DATABASE hindi_test
    CHARACTER SET utf8
    COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;

USE hindi_test;

CREATE TABLE `hindi` (
    `data` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `hindi` (`data`) VALUES
    ('कंप्यूटर');
```

This works on my install. If it doesn't work for you, something might be wrong with your server settings.

Comment: It doesnt work for me! I got ?????, Its showing there in phpmyadmin but not after I get it through API call. What to do with server setting??

Comment: @PalakDarji Sounds like an encoding problem in your browser.

Comment: @PalakDarji how did you solve that? Please help me out if this worked for you.

Answer (score 9):

You do not need database change, all you need is to alter table column.

```
ALTER TABLE `YOUR TABLE` CHANGE `data ` `data ` VARCHAR(1000) 
CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL;
```

This change works fine and very feasible.

Answer (score 3):

If the table has already been created and the problem is about storing (your) local language characters, `utf8_general_ci` or `utf16_general_ci` would be for you:
Fire following query:

`ALTER TABLE 'tbl_hindi' CHANGE 'data' 'data' VARCHAR(1000) CHARSET utf8 COLLATE utf16_general_ci DEFAULT '' NOT NULL;`

or

`ALTER TABLE 'tbl_hindi' CHANGE 'data' 'data' VARCHAR(1000) CHARSET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT '' NOT NULL;`

**If this too doesn't solve your problem, try altering the database collation to `utf16_general_ci`.**

Comment: I got the error after alter the table above command
COLLATION 'utf16_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8'
Then i ran the below one that's work for me

ALTER TABLE tb_contest_details  CHANGE termsCondition termsCondition VARCHAR(1200) CHARSET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT '' NOT NULL;

Comment: @RaviTyagi i had already stated in preface about "utf8_general_ci" or "utf16_general_ci"

Comment: Yes after some R&D it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

from your phpmyadmin change collation of your table  to utf16_general_ci...
Note: it worked for me..

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_hindi (
    data nvarchar(1000),
);
INSERT INTO tbl_hindi VALUES (N'कंप्यूटर');
SELECT * FROM tbl_hindi;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Below one work for me**

ALTER TABLE TableName CHANGE OldColumnName NewColumnName VARCHAR(1200) CHARSET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT '' NOT;

Answer (score -2):

just use N before the value like this
$sql="insert into indextbl Values('Null',N'$abc')";

Comment: I'm sorry, but how is this supposed to help? Also, why does your answer contain what looks like PHP?