# How can i insert Hindi record into mysql using netbean

Tags: java, mysql

i created table

```
CREATE TABLE `hindi` (
    `data` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `hindi` (`data`) VALUES
    ('कंप्यूटर');
```

but when i try to insert record vie net bean its store question mark in field.

Comment: does it work if you try to insert from sql client?

Comment: does following answers help to you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to insert Hindi language in Mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292898/how-to-insert-hindi-language-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the answer was deleted but it was correct as far as I know. You need to use NVARCHAR instead of VARCHAR.

Answer (score 0):

This is working

```
CREATE TABLE `hindi` (
`data` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO hindi(data) VALUES ("कंप्यूटर");
```