# I want to insert Hindi String in Mysql and Provide Search on Hindi Language Name Field

Tags: php, mysql, encoding

I am a new bee in php/mysql for Hindi Language

1.I need to insert Name in Hindi in mysql Table [st_name] via php.

2.Provide Search on Name field in Hindi Language.

MySql Table

```
CREATE TABLE `st_name` 
(
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `nameinhindi` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

I am using `<meta charset="UTF-8" />` Encoding

What I Have already tried is

```
Query1. mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');

Query2. mysql_query('SET names=utf8');

Query3. mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');

Query4. mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');

Query5. mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');

Query6. mysql_query('SET collation_connection=utf8_general_ci');

Query7. mysql_query("INSERT INTO `mahmoodialibrary`.`st_name` (`id` ,`nameinhindi`) VALUES (NULL , 'SomeNameInHindiFromHindiKeyboard');");
```

**Problem 1**: from Query 7 values successfully inserted into `st_name` but when I show it on Php page then i found '?????' string on name field.

**Problem 2:** Also I have to provide Search on Name Field but dont know How?

I am using collection for `table = 'utf8_general_ci'`

Comment: your table contains hindi script or not? In php page you should include some coding like this"<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />"

Comment: and also read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292898/how-to-insert-hindi-language-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Did you set proper charset in the HTML Head section?

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

and you are using PHP code in page.

```
  header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
```

and also read this [@Owen Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202205/how-to-make-mysql-handle-utf-8-properly/202246)

you can read this following article [How to insert Indian Language in MYSQL](http://jpsolution.wordpress.com/tag/insert-hindi-text-in-mysql/)