# How to send kannada words in url using C#?

Tags: c#

I have some SMS service api, which sends the message to the user's mobile. But when I am trying to send Kannada words, it's sending question marks.

Example: [http://sms1.epsro.com/send.aspx?message=ದಿನಾಂಕ&mobileno=](http://sms1.epsro.com/send.aspx?message=%E0%B2%A6%E0%B2%BF%E0%B2%A8%E0%B2%BE%E0%B2%82%E0%B2%95&mobileno=)

In response, I am getting "??????".

Can you please give some solution, so that I can get the exact Kannada word in mobile?

Comment: hope this link helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25363151/how-to-fetch-hindi-text-indian-local-language-from-mysql-database

Answer (score 0):

Use the [HttpUtility.UrlEncodeUnicode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencodeunicode(v=vs.110).aspx) function.  It's been obsoleted, but still may work for you.  Note - it is non-standards compliant.