# how to pass hindi fonts from clients to server using ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, utf-8

I am using ajax request to send a value from client side to server side to insert in mysql database using ajax request. The value is in hindi language (हिन्दी मतलब जाने). But on client side when i alert it i get the hindi text as shown above but after the server side request is processed it gets inserted in the database as `%u0939%u093F%u0928%u094D%u0926%u0940 %u092E%u0924%...`

i have used in the client side

```
request1h[k].setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;");
request1h[k].send(requestDatah);
```

and on the server side header with php

```
<?php header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");
```

then i read about utf8_encode and used that on the post value also

```
$value1 = utf8_decode($_POST['values']);
```

but still i can't insert the hindi text in the database as it is. Please help me what to do ?

Comment: in your server part when you dump `var_dump($_POST);`  able to see the text in hindi...?

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292898/how-to-insert-hindi-language-in-mysql

Comment: actually problem is only with the server side while using ajax.. if i dont use ajax i am able to use it properly without any error

Comment: JavaScript strings are in 16 bit unicode, hence the `uxxxx` form. The `%` comes from the url-encoding triggered by `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` but PHP should be able to handle it. So give UTF-16 a try.

Comment: @deamentiaemundi: its not working

Comment: @SinghRajputKushagra ok. Or better: not ok. It could be UCS-2, too, but all Javascript engines innards I know do UTF-16, Did you chaneg teh DB, too? See e.g. here; https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf16.html for further information but from what I know UTF-8 should work for the Hindi character set. Mmh...please try `$value1 = utf8_decode(urldecode($_POST['values']));` and check your database for the correct character-set settings.

Comment: It won't be `UCS2` or `utf16`, even though `0939` is the ucs2 for `ह`, etc.  AJAX will "url encode", so, you need to "url_decode" it before putting into a `CHARACTER SET utf8` MySQL column.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/q/279170/1255289)

Answer (score 0):

for insert on your database you can try with these
setup database with UTF8 AND COLLECTION UTF8 GENERAL

an for show language hindi you can put on your page HTML :
the next:

```
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
```

for spetial character  and other language you can use utf8

Answer (score 0):

Use `btoa` function for Encode a string in base-64: It returns the value as a string, representing the strings encoded `base-64`.

*By default, built-in functions in JavaScript, such as `btoa` and `atob`, do not support Unicode strings, as both functions treat all its characters as 16-bit-encoded strings. so you have to use first `encodeURIComponent` function.*

```js
base64_encode = function(str = "") {
  return btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(str)));
};

function log(message) {
  var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
  client.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      json = JSON.parse(this.response);
      console.log(json.form);
    }
  };
  client.open("POST", '//httpbin.org/post');
  client.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  client.send(message);
}
data = "key_name=" + base64_encode("हिन्दी मतलब जाने");
log(data);
```

If you need to decode that base64 to value in PHP file where you post data, use this:

```php
// this will return 'हिन्दी मतलब जाने'
$value = base64_decode($_POST['key_name']);
```

And when you enter data into the database, make sure that the character set `utf8_general_ci` in your table must be set.

If this is your problem, you can convert the table using the following query:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `YOUR_TABLE_NAME` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```