# insert hindi data into database in particular font(devlys)

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert data into MySQL table which is in Hindi. My data is in excel which has font devlys 10.of I copy and paste it in query it does not show up. But if I copy some hindi text from Google translator it takes. I Have tried to use CSV for that particular font but after import it doesn't show Hindi rather shows special characters.

For database ,table and other thing I have checked the things are set properly for utf 8 collation which works well.

If I insert data from translator it shows in Hindi . So question is how to show devlys 10 Hindi font data.?

**here is my code...**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Demo - Import Excel file data in mysql database using PHP, Upload Excel file data in database</title>
<meta name="description" content="This tutorial will learn how to import excel sheet data in mysql database using php. Here, first upload an excel sheet into your server and then click to import it into database. All column of excel sheet will store into your corrosponding database table."/>
<meta name="keywords" content="import excel file data in mysql, upload ecxel file in mysql, upload data, code to import excel data in mysql database, php, Mysql, Ajax, Jquery, Javascript, download, upload, upload excel file,mysql"/>
</head>
<body>

     <?php

      define ("DB_HOST", "localhost"); // set database host
     define ("DB_USER", "root"); // set database user
     define ("DB_PASS",""); // set database password
     define ("DB_NAME","uor"); // set database name

     $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die("Couldn't make b 
     connection.");
     $db = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link) or die("Couldn't select database");

     $databasetable = "data";




     set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'Classes/');
     include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

     // This is the file path to be uploaded.
      $inputFileName = 'discussdesk.xlsx'; 

       try {
       $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
      } catch(Exception $e) {
        die('Error loading file 
       "'.pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": 
      '.$e->getMessage());
      }


     $allDataInSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()-
    >toArray(null,true,true,true);
     $arrayCount = count($allDataInSheet);  // Here get total count of row in 
      that 
      Excel sheet


     for($i=1;$i<=$arrayCount;$i++){
     $name = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["A"]);
     $email = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["B"]);
     //$hname = mb_detect_encoding($email);

     if($name) {
         mysql_set_charset('utf8');
     $insertTable= mysql_query("insert into data (name, email) 
    values('".$name."', 
    '".$email."')");


    $msg = 'Record has been added. <div style="Padding:20px 0 0 0;"><a 
    href="">Go 
    Back to tutorial</a></div>';
    } else {
    $msg = 'Record already exist. <div style="Padding:20px 0 0 0;"><a href="">Go 
     Back to tutorial</a></div>';
    }
    }
    echo "<div style='font: bold 18px arial,verdana;padding: 45px 0 0 
    500px;'>".$msg."</div>";


    ?>
    <body>
   </html>
```

Comment: What is your database encoding? Make sure everything is UTF-8!

Comment: yes everything is utf-8

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert Hindi language in Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292898/how-to-insert-hindi-language-in-mysql)

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292898/how-to-insert-hindi-language-in-mysql

Comment: i am using csv file

Comment: How is the CSV encoded?

Comment: i am using devlys font to convert English data into hindi

Comment: when i copy hindi data from google translater it works otherwise it shows special character in database

Comment: make sure your `character set : utf8 & collation : utf8_unicode_ci`

Comment: you shouldn't need to rely on a font. That's where your problem lies then.

Comment: Encoding is the issue, but there are two factors here: the encoding of the database, and the encoding of the CSV file! I would make sure they are the same (UTF-8 in this case). Check the documentation of whatever you are using to edit/read the CSV.

Comment: Oh! That edit to the OP changes things. You are importing direct from Excel. The documentation for PHPExcel should help you out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I think is Excel fonts or any other font can not be stored in db.
You only can store data only