# How to insert hindi text by passing parameter in mysql database

Tags: sql-server

I am unable to insert Hindi text with passing parameter  Please guid me through sql query and passing parametr  only .

It is working --

```
insert into  MyTable (HindiText) values (N'जिए जाने किस रस्म जारी है')
```

but it is not working (Why)

```
declare @HindiText nvarchar(max)='जिए जाने किस रस्म जारी है';
insert into  MyTable (HindiText) values (N@HindiText)

declare @HindiText nvarchar(max)='जिए जाने किस रस्म जारी है';
insert into  MyTable (HindiText) values (N@HindiText)
```

Comment: Hi please share your database definition like collation and other information .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert Hindi language in Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292898/how-to-insert-hindi-language-in-mysql)

Comment: Hi think this link can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292898/how-to-insert-hindi-language-in-mysql

Comment: `declare @HindiText nvarchar(max) = N'जिए जाने किस रस्म जारी है';` and then just `VALUES (@HindiText)` - the `N` goes before the string, not the variable.

Comment: @pascalsanchez Don't change the tags like that - it's a question about SQL server, not MySQL.

Comment: @Qirel and the title i speak about mysql database ...... no SQL Server

Comment: But the syntax is SQL server. There is no `NVARCHAR` syntax in MySQL, it's SQL server. Appears the OP is confused about the title and his own tags and his code.. We need more details.

Comment: Here's a thought - JUST STOP EDITING POSTS into your own idea of perfection.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a demo for you Please try this.

```
declare @HindiText nvarchar(max)=N'जिए जाने किस रस्म जारी है';
insert into  MyTable (HindiText) values (@HindiText)
```

**NOTE**: Make sure the data type of table column is **NVARCHAR**. And before write Hindi text their sud be **N** is there.

Comment: The way you answered I already tried that is working fine , but want to work with parameter.

Comment: I have updated my answer please check it, I hope its work for you.

Comment: suppose there is a variable already hold the value like 'जिए जाने किस रस्म जारी है' then how you will add N as Prefix.