# How do I select and display a 'Hindi' language stored in database table using codeigniter

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter and mySQL and want to retrieve that Hindi text 'नमस्ते दुनिया'  and display it using `SELECT * FROM table where text LIKE '%नमस्ते%'`
which I am unable to do.

Comment: you  want to make sure that your charset is set to utf8 at least [ReadThis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328968/how-to-store-unicode-in-mysql)

Comment: charset is utf-8 and dbcollat is utf8_general_ci

Comment: maybe codeignite is not passing queries in unicode format , you may want to check that out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert Hindi language in Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292898/how-to-insert-hindi-language-in-mysql)

Comment: Does that query work directly in your mysql without the use of codeigniter? Check that first to make sure that there's nothing wrong with the database collation and charset first.

Comment: @Parin Nagda where is your error comes??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE Table convert to CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

This worked for me

Comment: please marked this as accepted answer if it solved your problem for future readers..