# How to insert kruti dev 010 fonts in mysql workbench table database

Tags: mysql, netbeans, fonts, mysql-workbench

I have tried all the possible solutions available on internet like

- change character set to utf-8 and collate utf-8_unicode_general_ci
- change fonts in preferences
- edit in wb_options.xml file

Is mysql Workbench doesn't support kruti dev 010 fonts in table columns??

```
CREATE TABLE `पदस्थापना_न्यायालय`.`उत्तराधिकारी` (
  `यूनिक_कोड` BIGINT(200) NOT NULL,
  `जीवनसाथीकानाम` NVARCHAR(200) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci' NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`यूनिक_कोड`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `यूनिककोड_UNIQUE` (`यूनिककोड` ASC) VISIBLE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

Is I have to name schema and table names in english ??

Comment: [1] Are you getting some specific error when you run that SQL to create your table? Regardless, can you update your question to clarify the precise problem you are facing? [2] Do any of the answers to this question help: [How to insert Hindi language in Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11292898/2985643)

Comment: Please provide `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%'`

Answer (score 0):

- Change `NVARCHAR` to `VARCHAR`.
- It looks like the column being declared UNIQUE has not been declared.
- A `PRIMARY KEY` is a `UNIQUE` is a `INDEX`.  That is, there is no need to respecify the PK as being UNIQUE.